# Salt: Can I use an argument from the command line as a jinja variable?

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

Given a file called package-list, I want to do something like:

```
salt state.sls install-packages list_to_install=package-list
```

...and then in the sls:

```
packages:
    pkg.installed:
        - names:
            {% include list_to_install %}
```

Comment: Might be relevant: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/cli/index.html#calling-the-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using Pillar:

```
packages:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - pkgs: {{ salt['pillar.get']('packages') }}
```

Then pass the `pillar` argument containing valid YAML:

```
salt '*' state.sls package-list pillar='{packages: [foo, bar, baz]}'
```